# MAX MSP // How can i controll visualisation with incoming audio signal?

Tags: max, msp, max-msp-jitter, audio-video-sync

do anyone work with **MAX MSP** and can help me?

how can i control videosignal with incoming audio signal. I would like to swith video input signal betwen 2 cameras, when the music changes. How can i read a frequency or bpm and by changing send signal to switch camera or visualisation? Have someone an idea? I would be glad to read a cople of ideas. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Max 5 or later, they have really great built in help files. For instance, when you open Max, go to Help -> Jitter Tutorials. I'd start by reading the first few just to get a handle of how jitter deals with data and matrices. Then specifically for video switching, read tutorial 8: Simple Mixing and 9: More mixing.

Then read tutorial 21: Working with Live Video and Audio Input, and then Tutorial 22: Working with Video output, that'll cover your input and outputs.

For audio analysis, you can either grab some prebuilt stuff in the Max toolbox website. MSP has similar tutorials to Jitter, I'd suggest reading the few introduction one, then you can jump to MSP Tutorial 6: A review of Fundamentals, Tutorial 25: Using the FFT, and Tutorial 23: Viewing Signal Data.

Those should get you started and on the right path.

Also check out the CNMAT set of externals, as there is a lot of really useful prebuilt stuff in there.

Comment: @OlegPeP if that answers your question, accept the answer and ask another question on stack :)